# How to convert JSONArray to JSON?

Tags: json

I have file with JSON objects separated by new line (a.k.a JSONArray / JSONLines):

```
{'a': 123, 'b': 2, 'v': 0}
{'a': 240, 'b': 3, 'v': 0}
...
```

**How I can convert it to native JSON (in command line)?**

To looks like:

```
[{'a': 123, 'b': 2, 'v': 0}, {'a': 240, 'b': 3, 'v': 0}]
```

Comment: Aren't you converting JSON to a JSONArray?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long searching I've found a perfect solution with [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq -s -c '[.[]]' input.jsonlines > output.json
```

That's it!